# Using Case IF statements in queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement

**Using Case IF statements in queries**   (SQL 2008)

I have servers with 3 instances each. I am doing **one** query to run on all of them.  part of the query will filter the ids for each server i.e 123 for server1.

```
select COUNT(*) from Department Dep  
where Dep.LocationID in   
(1,2,3, -- Server1  
4,5,6, -- Server2  
7,8,9 --Server3  
)
```

I can filter as above for all ids and get the result. As the table is very large (2 miilon rows) it may be best to filter just whats in the tabel i.e 123 for server1. Although it does not make much difference to the time it takes to complete.

I could do this

```
if @@SERVERNAME ='Server1'  
  Begin  
  select COUNT(*) from Department Dep  
  where dep.LocationID in   
  (1,2,3)  
  End  

if @@SERVERNAME ='Server2'  
  Begin  
  select COUNT(*) from Department Dep  
   where dep.LocationID in   
  (4,5,6)  
  End  


if @@SERVERNAME ='Server3'  
  Begin  
  select COUNT(*) from Department Dep  
 where dep.LocationID in    
  (7,8,9)  
  End
```

So if i am running the query above on server2 i would filter only (4,5,6)

I would want to join this result to another queries hence looking for a better way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're asking here.  Could you clarify?

Comment: do your three queries and insert the results into a table variable (or temp table), and then do your final select against the table variable.

Comment: sorry hope its clearer now

Comment: Do you have something against formatting the code? It's much easier to read if you either use indentation or the `{}` button so that StackOverflow can format your code (and differentiate it from actual text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with three conditions in your WHERE clause:

```
  select COUNT(*) from Employee emp  
  where 
  (@@SERVERNAME = 'Server1' AND emp.LocationID in (1,2,3))
    OR 
  (@@SERVERNAME = 'Server2' AND emp.LocationID in (4,5,6))
    OR 
  (@@SERVERNAME = 'Server3' AND emp.LocationID in (7,8,9))
```

Comment: Glad it worked - though in fairness Allen's answer is "better" since adding servers and/or locations wouldn't require you to change the queries (if that's a concern).

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to do this would be to put the server name (or a related key) in a `locations` lookup table. Then you could do this quite simply:

```
select COUNT(*) from Employee emp  
where emp.LocationID in   
(select locationID from locations where server = @@SERVERNAME)
```

This would also allow you to add additional instances without changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to 'persist' a single result set across all three queries, you can store the output in a temp table (or table variable) and then use that object in your final query.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #ServerOutput (ServerName VARCHAR(20), TotalRecords INT)

IF @@SERVERNAME = 'Server1'
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #ServerOutput (ServerName, TotalRecords)
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME, COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords
    FROM Employee emp
    WHERE emp.Location IN (1,2,3)
  END

SELECT * FROM #ServerOutput
```